# How to set default color configurable product on product page in pwa-studio with Magento 2.3.2?

Tags: magento2, pwa-studio

In PWA-studio default random colors are loading, but I want to load default Product colors.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the swatch colors for the product page?

That component is not finished in PWA Studio's example theme, and right now those swatches are just placeholders for right now.

Comment: Yes, I talked abt that.
Actually I have completed that with dynamic product color fetch on the product details page.
But the thing is what that depends on magento lat version.